# LINQ: Updating an independent grid

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have two grids, `gSummary` and `gInput`. `gSummary` does a bit of data massaging (totals, etc) from the DB and `gInput` is where the user can directly modify the data itself.

I'm finding that the data is submitted correctly (the DB is successfully atomically updated at every change) but that unless I refresh the entire `gSummary` table, the `gSummary` info is out of date and I have to set the `DataSource` again. Is there some way I can update single rows, or somehow refresh the data without refreshing *all* the data?

edit: I'm using Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ObservableCollection<T>` then manage the changes yourself. (Which should be fairly straightforward.)

Comment: This is not my problem. The problem is not that I'm not being told it's updating - the datasource for `gSummary` is getting dirty and I can't refresh easily. When the user inputs data, it gets dirty, and I have events to flag when this occurs. I iterate through the `gSummary` data source and it's an outdated list. I want to know if there is a way I can keep it up to date with the changes in `gInput`. I have answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to re-query the database with a query for only the changed field so the whole thing didn't have to all refresh.

so instead of `LinqObject.RecalculateSummary()` in the partial class, I called `DataAccessObject.recalculateSummary(LinqObject)`. Not the best solution ever but works for me.

Comment: If anyone has any more answers, please add an answer. I'm happy to mark a non-hacky answer as the right one (if there *is* one...)